# Caixa de seleção

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, sql, sql-server

estou com dificuldade em criar um pagina na web onde tenha caixas de seleçao dependentes. Por exemplo, apos selecionar a primeira caixa os valores da segunda variam conforme a opçao selecionada. Os campos das duas caixas (valores) vêm de um banco de dados. Pode ser usando javascript, jquerry, etc.

Alguem pode me ajudar ? 
Obrigado

Comment: OBS: Preciso acessar o banco de dados (sql server) e usar os valores de determinada coluna para inserir na caixa de seleções. E as colunas têm de ser dependentes uma da outra (exemplo estado e cidade). Além disso iria precisar inserir os valores de volta numa nova linha da tabela do SQL.

Answer (score 3):

Pablo,

Você pode utilizar esse exemplo de seleção de "País / Estado / Cidade".

Basicamente é trabalhar com os eventos "onchange" do select box:

```
<form name="myform" id="myForm">
  <select id="countySel" size="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select Country --</option>
    </select>
     <br>
    <br>

    <select id="stateSel" size="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select State--</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>    
    <select id="citySel" size="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select City--</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <select id="zipSel" size="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select Zip--</option>
    </select>
</form>

var countryStateInfo = {
    "USA": {
        "California": {
            "Los Angeles": ["90001", "90002", "90003", "90004"],
            "San Diego": ["92093", "92101"]
        },
        "Texas": {
            "Dallas": ["75201", "75202"],
            "Austin": ["73301", "73344"]
        }
    },
    "India": {
        "Assam": {
            "Dispur": ["781005"],
            "Guwahati" : ["781030", "781030"]
        },
        "Gujarat": {
            "Vadodara" : ["390011", "390020"],
            "Surat" : ["395006", "395002"]
        }
    }
}


window.onload = function () {

    //Get html elements
    var countySel = document.getElementById("countySel");
    var stateSel = document.getElementById("stateSel"); 
    var citySel = document.getElementById("citySel");
    var zipSel = document.getElementById("zipSel");

    //Load countries
    for (var country in countryStateInfo) {
        countySel.options[countySel.options.length] = new Option(country, country);
    }

    //County Changed
    countySel.onchange = function () {

         stateSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
         citySel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
         zipSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first

         if (this.selectedIndex < 1)
             return; // done

         for (var state in countryStateInfo[this.value]) {
             stateSel.options[stateSel.options.length] = new Option(state, state);
         }
    }

    //State Changed
    stateSel.onchange = function () {        

         citySel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
         zipSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first

         if (this.selectedIndex < 1)
             return; // done

         for (var city in countryStateInfo[countySel.value][this.value]) {
             citySel.options[citySel.options.length] = new Option(city, city);
         }
    }

    //City Changed
    citySel.onchange = function () {
        zipSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first

        if (this.selectedIndex < 1)
            return; // done

        var zips = countryStateInfo[countySel.value][stateSel.value][this.value];
        for (var i = 0; i < zips.length; i++) {
            zipSel.options[zipSel.options.length] = new Option(zips[i], zips[i]);
        }
    }   
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/patelriki13/m1ezs70o/

Comment: Ótima resposta! O exemplo é perfeito, parabéns! Creio que vai ajudar bastante.

Comment: Mas Marcelo, como faço pra fazer com que os valores sejam extraidos do banco de dados?. Por exemplo, aqui ele define "manualmente" os valores. Não posso definir dessa maneira, pois o numero de determinada caixa pode aumentar ou diminuir.

Comment: Uma forma é utilizar durante o evento "onchange" uma chamada jQuery GET para sua aplicação Rest. Utilize esse link: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/. Qual linguagem você está utilizando como Backend?

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/209742)

Comment: Ok @JoãoMartins, alterei a resposta conforme sugerido.